# If file name contains specific text then execute

Tags: vba, excel, filenames

I have code that loops through a folder and adds text values to G1, H1, I1 etc etc. to Workbooks.

In Pic 1 you see I have several files in my folder. Different Excel files or Workbooks get different Text Values added to them.

The Text Values to be added to the "Professional" Workbook are different from the Text Values to be added to "ProfessionalAddress" or "ProfessionalCommunication".

I have tried to use `InStr` but this will take any file name that contains a certain piece of text.
For example I have several files that contain the word "Professional" this means that the code then adds the text values for "Professional" file to all files that contain the text "Professional".

I need when a file name contains "Professional" add these Text Values, when a file contains "ProfessionalAddress" add these Text Values. Likewise for "Meeting" "Organization" "Customer".

Pic 1 
[image]

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()
'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

            If InStr(myFile, "Professional") > 0 Then

    'Add Column Headings
      wb.Worksheets(1).Range("F1").Value = "Error code"
      Range("G1").Value = "Error description"
      Range("H1").Value = "ActionCode"
      Range("I1").Value = "ProfessionalId"
      Range("J1").Value = "StatusCode"
      Range("K1").Value = "ProfessionalTypeCode"
      Range("L1").Value = "StatusDate"
      Range("M1").Value = "Qualification"
      Range("N1").Value = "ProfessionalSubtypeCode"
      Range("O1").Value = "FirstName"
      Range("P1").Value = "MiddleName"
      Range("Q1").Value = "LastName"
      Range("R1").Value = "SecondLastName"
      Range("S1").Value = "MeNumber"
      Range("T1").Value = "ImsPrescriberId"
      Range("U1").Value = "NdcNumber"
      Range("V1").Value = "TitleCode"
      Range("W1").Value = "ProfessionalSuffixCode"
      Range("X1").Value = "GenderCode"
      Range("Y1").Value = "Reserved for future use"
      Range("Z1").Value = "Reserved for future use"
      Range("AA1").Value = "Reserved for future use"
      Range("AB1").Value = "Reserved for future use"
      Range("AC1").Value = "SourceDataLevelCode"
      Range("AD1").Value = "PatientsPerDay"
      Range("AE1").Value = "PrimarySpecialtyCode"
      Range("AF1").Value = "SecondarySpecialtyCode"
      Range("AG1").Value = "TertiarySpecialtyCode"
      Range("AH1").Value = "NationalityCode"
      Range("AI1").Value = "TypeOfStudy"
      Range("AJ1").Value = "UniversityAffiliation"
      Range("AK1").Value = "SpeakerStatusCode"
      Range("AL1").Value = "OneKeyId"
      Range("AM1").Value = "NucleusId"
      Range("AN1").Value = "Suffix"
      Range("AO1").Value = "ClientField1"
      Range("AP1").Value = "ClientField2"
      Range("AQ1").Value = "ClientField3"
      Range("AR1").Value = "ClientField4"
      Range("AS1").Value = "ClientField5"
      Range("AT1").Value = "Reserved for future use"
      Range("AU1").Value = "NPICountry"
      Range("AV1").Value = "CountryCode"
      Range("AW1").Value = "Reserved for future use"
      Range("AX1").Value = "MassachusettsId"
      Range("AY1").Value = "NPIId"
      Range("AZ1").Value = "UniversityCity"
      Range("BA1").Value = "UniversityPostalArea"

    End If

    If InStr(myFile, "ProfessionalAddress") > 0 Then

    'Add Column Headings
      wb.Worksheets(1).Range("F1").Value = "Error code"
      Range("G1").Value = "Error description"
      Range("H1").Value = "ActionCode"
      Range("I1").Value = "ProfessionalAddressId"
      Range("J1").Value = "EffectiveDate"
      Range("K1").Value = "StatusCode"
      Range("L1").Value = "ProfessionalId"
      Range("M1").Value = "AddressTypeCode"
      Range("N1").Value = "StatusDate"
      Range("O1").Value = "Reserved for future use"
      Range("P1").Value = "AddressLine1"
      Range("Q1").Value = "AddressLine2"
      Range("R1").Value = "AddressLine3"
      Range("S1").Value = "City"
      Range("T1").Value = "State"
      Range("U1").Value = "PostalArea"
      Range("V1").Value = "PostalAreaExtension"
      Range("W1").Value = "CountryCode"
      Range("X1").Value = "Reserved for future use"
      Range("Y1").Value = "Reserved for future use"
      Range("Z1").Value = "Reserved for future use"
      Range("AA1").Value = "DeaNumber"
      Range("AB1").Value = "DeaExpirationDate"
      Range("AC1").Value = "LocationName"
      Range("AD1").Value = "EndDate"
      Range("AE1").Value = "N/A"

    End If

    If InStr(myFile, "ProfessionalStateLicense") > 0 Then

    'Add Column Headings
      wb.Worksheets(1).Range("F1").Value = "Error code"
      Range("G1").Value = "Error description"
      Range("H1").Value = "ActionCode"
      Range("I1").Value = "ProfessionalLicenseId"
      Range("J1").Value = "EffectiveDate"
      Range("K1").Value = "EndDate"
      Range("L1").Value = "ProfessionalId"
      Range("M1").Value = "StateLicenseNumber"
      Range("N1").Value = "StateLicenseState"
      Range("O1").Value = "StateLicenseExpirationDate"
      Range("P1").Value = "SamplingStatusCode"
      Range("Q1").Value = "Reserved for future use"
      Range("R1").Value = "N/A"

    End If


     If InStr(myFile, "ProfessionalCommunication") > 0 Then

    'Add Column Headings
      wb.Worksheets(1).Range("F1").Value = "Error code"
      Range("G1").Value = "Error description"
      Range("H1").Value = "ActionCode"
      Range("I1").Value = "ProfessionalCommunicationId"
      Range("J1").Value = "ProfessionalId"
      Range("K1").Value = "CommunicationTypeCode"
      Range("L1").Value = "CommunicationValue1"
      Range("M1").Value = "CommunicationValue2"
      Range("N1").Value = "ProfessionalAddressId"
      Range("O1").Value = "N/A"

    End If

      If InStr(myFile, "Organization") > 0 Then

    'Add Column Headings
      wb.Worksheets(1).Range("F1").Value = "Error code"
      Range("G1").Value = "Error description"
      Range("H1").Value = "ActionCode"
      Range("I1").Value = "OrganizationId"
      Range("J1").Value = "StatusCode"
      Range("K1").Value = "OrganizationTypeCode"
      Range("L1").Value = "StatusDate"
      Range("M1").Value = "Reserved for future use"
      Range("N1").Value = "OrganizationSubtypeCode"
      Range("O1").Value = "OrganizationName"
      Range("P1").Value = "NPICountry"
      Range("Q1").Value = "Reserved for future use"
      Range("R1").Value = "Reserved for future use"
      Range("S1").Value = "Reserved for future use"
      Range("T1").Value = "Reserved for future use"
      Range("U1").Value = "SourceDataLevelCode"
      Range("V1").Value = "Reserved for future use"
      Range("W1").Value = "Reserved for future use"
      Range("X1").Value = "OneKeyId"
      Range("Y1").Value = "FederalTaxId"
      Range("Z1").Value = "Reserved for future use"
      Range("AA1").Value = "NucleusId"
      Range("AB1").Value = "Reserved for future use"
      Range("AC1").Value = "ClientField1"
      Range("AD1").Value = "ClientField2"
      Range("AE1").Value = "ClientField3"
      Range("AF1").Value = "ClientField4"
      Range("AG1").Value = "ClientField5"
      Range("AH1").Value = "MassachusettsId"
      Range("AI1").Value = "NPIId"
      Range("AJ1").Value = "N/A"

    End If

      If InStr(myFile, "OrganizationAddress") > 0 Then

    'Add Column Headings
      wb.Worksheets(1).Range("F1").Value = "Error code"
      Range("G1").Value = "Error description"
      Range("H1").Value = "ActionCode"
      Range("I1").Value = "OrganizationAddressId"
      Range("J1").Value = "EffectiveDate"
      Range("K1").Value = "StatusCode"
      Range("L1").Value = "OrganizationId"
      Range("M1").Value = "AddressTypeCode"
      Range("N1").Value = "StatusDate"
      Range("O1").Value = "Reserved for future use"
      Range("P1").Value = "AddressLine1"
      Range("Q1").Value = "AddressLine2"
      Range("R1").Value = "AddressLine3"
      Range("S1").Value = "City"
      Range("T1").Value = "State"
      Range("U1").Value = "PostalArea"
      Range("V1").Value = "PostalAreaExtension"
      Range("W1").Value = "CountryCode"
      Range("X1").Value = "Reserved for future use"
      Range("Y1").Value = "Reserved for future use"
      Range("Z1").Value = "Reserved for future use"
      Range("AA1").Value = "DeaNumber"
      Range("AB1").Value = "DeaExpirationDate"
      Range("AC1").Value = "LocationName"
      Range("AD1").Value = "EndDate"
      Range("AE1").Value = "N/A"

    End If

      If InStr(myFile, "OrganizationCommunication") > 0 Then

    'Add Column Headings
      wb.Worksheets(1).Range("F1").Value = "Error code"
      Range("G1").Value = "Error description"
      Range("H1").Value = "ActionCode"
      Range("I1").Value = "OrganizationCommunicationId"
      Range("J1").Value = "OrganizationId"
      Range("K1").Value = "CommunicationTypeCode"
      Range("L1").Value = "CommunicationValue1"
      Range("M1").Value = "CommunicationValue2"
      Range("N1").Value = "OrganizationAddressId"
      Range("O1").Value = "N/A"

    End If

     If InStr(myFile, "OrganizationSpecialty") > 0 Then

    'Add Column Headings
      wb.Worksheets(1).Range("F1").Value = "Error code"
      Range("G1").Value = "Error description"
      Range("H1").Value = "ActionCode"
      Range("I1").Value = "OrganizationSpecialtyId"
      Range("J1").Value = "OrganizationId"
      Range("K1").Value = "SpecialtyTypeCode"
      Range("L1").Value = "SpecialtyCode"
      Range("M1").Value = "N/A"    

    End If

      If InStr(myFile, "Agreement01_MSD") > 0 Then

    'Add Column Headings
      wb.Worksheets(1).Range("F1").Value = "Error code"
      Range("G1").Value = "Error description"
      Range("H1").Value = "ActionCode"
      Range("I1").Value = "AgreementId"
      Range("J1").Value = "CompanyId"
      Range("K1").Value = "AgreementName"
      Range("L1").Value = "AgreementType"
      Range("M1").Value = "StatusCode"
      Range("N1").Value = "Description"
      Range("O1").Value = "AgreementDate"
      Range("P1").Value = "CustomerId"
      Range("Q1").Value = "ApprovalDate"
      Range("R1").Value = "StartDate"
      Range("S1").Value = "EndDate"
      Range("T1").Value = "SignatureDate"
      Range("U1").Value = "SecondaryCustomerId"
      Range("V1").Value = "AgreementCountry"
      Range("W1").Value = "ClientField1"
      Range("X1").Value = "ClientField2"
      Range("Y1").Value = "ClientField3"
      Range("Z1").Value = "ClientField4"
      Range("AA1").Value = "ClientField5"
      Range("AB1").Value = "ClientDate1"
      Range("AC1").Value = "ClientDate2"
      Range("AD1").Value = "ClientNumber1"
      Range("AE1").Value = "ClientNumber2"
      Range("AF1").Value = "DataSourceId"
      Range("AG1").Value = "CreationUser"
      Range("AH1").Value = "CommentText"
      Range("AI1").Value = "FirstName"
      Range("AJ1").Value = "MiddleName"
      Range("AK1").Value = "LastName"
      Range("AL1").Value = "AddressId"
      Range("AM1").Value = "AddressLine1"
      Range("AN1").Value = "AddressLine2"
      Range("AO1").Value = "AddressLine3"
      Range("AP1").Value = "City"
      Range("AQ1").Value = "State"
      Range("AR1").Value = "PostalArea"
      Range("AS1").Value = "Country"
      Range("AT1").Value = "SecondaryFirstName"
      Range("AU1").Value = "SecondaryMiddleName"
      Range("AV1").Value = "SecondaryLastName"
      Range("AW1").Value = "SecondaryAddressId"
      Range("AX1").Value = "SecondaryAddressLine1"
      Range("AY1").Value = "SecondaryAddressLine2"
      Range("AZ1").Value = "SecondaryAddressLine3"
      Range("BA1").Value = "SecondaryCity"
      Range("BB1").Value = "SecondaryState"
      Range("BC1").Value = "SecondaryPostalArea"
      Range("BD1").Value = "SecondaryCountry"
      Range("BE1").Value = "EventVenue"
      Range("BG1").Value = "EventName"
      Range("BG1").Value = "EventDate"
      Range("BH1").Value = "AgreementVenueOrganizer"
      Range("BI1").Value = "AgreementReason"

    End If

    If InStr(myFile, "Consent11_MSD") > 0 Then

    'Add Column Headings
      wb.Worksheets(1).Range("F1").Value = "Error code"
      Range("G1").Value = "Error description"
      Range("H1").Value = "ActionCode"
      Range("I1").Value = "ConsentId"
      Range("J1").Value = "CompanyId"
      Range("K1").Value = "ConsentType"
      Range("L1").Value = "ConsentIndicator"
      Range("M1").Value = "CustomerId"
      Range("N1").Value = "ExpensePurposeCode"
      Range("O1").Value = "EffectiveDate"
      Range("P1").Value = "EndDate"
      Range("Q1").Value = "ConsentDate"
      Range("R1").Value = "CommentText"
      Range("S1").Value = "AgreementId"
      Range("T1").Value = "CustomerExpenseId"
      Range("U1").Value = "MeetingId"
      Range("V1").Value = "DataSourceId"
      Range("W1").Value = "ClientField1"
      Range("X1").Value = "ClientField2"
      Range("Y1").Value = "ClientField3"
      Range("Z1").Value = "ClientField4"
      Range("AA1").Value = "ClientField5"
      Range("AB1").Value = "N/A"

    End If

    'Save and Close Workbook
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

STRIPPED DOWN CODE FOR TEST

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()
'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

      myFile = "20170614Agreement01_MSD.xls"

            If getTextBtwnNumbers(myFile) = "Agreement" Then

    'Add Text
      wb.Worksheets(1).Range("F1").Value = "Error code"
      Range("G1").Value = "Error description"
      Range("H1").Value = "ActionCode"
      Range("I1").Value = "ProfessionalId"
      Range("J1").Value = "StatusCode"
      Range("K1").Value = "ProfessionalTypeCode"
      Range("L1").Value = "StatusDate"
      Range("M1").Value = "Qualification"
      'etc etc etc

    End If

    'Save and Close Workbook
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Private Function getTextBtwnNumbers(s As String) As String
    Dim pos1 As Long, pos2 As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        If pos1 = 0 Then
            Select Case Asc(Mid(s, i, 1))
            Case 65 To 90, 97 To 122
                pos1 = i
            End Select
        Else
            For j = pos1 To Len(s)
                Select Case Asc(Mid(s, j, 1))
                Case 65 To 90, 97 To 122
                Case Else
                    pos2 = j ' - 1
                    Exit For
                End Select
            Next j
        End If

        If pos1 <> 0 And pos2 <> 0 Then Exit For
    Next i

    If pos1 <> 0 And pos2 <> 0 Then
        getTextBtwnNumbers = Trim(Mid(s, pos1, pos2 - pos1))
    Else
        getTextBtwnNumbers = "Invalid Text Format"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: yep I could definitely of done with minimal in mind here. Thank you for the tip :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that there is no space in the words in the file names. In such a scenario it becomes difficult to prevent **False Positives**.

Having said that if the text that you are looking for will always be between 2 numbers; for example `Agreement` is between `20170614` and `01` in `20170614Agreement01_MSD.xls` then we may take this approach

Add this function to your code

```
Private Function getTextBtwnNumbers(s As String) As String
    Dim pos1 As Long, pos2 As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        If pos1 = 0 Then
            Select Case Asc(Mid(s, i, 1))
            Case 65 To 90, 97 To 122
                pos1 = i
            End Select
        Else
            For j = pos1 To Len(s)
                Select Case Asc(Mid(s, j, 1))
                Case 65 To 90, 97 To 122
                Case Else
                    pos2 = j ' - 1
                    Exit For
                End Select
            Next j
        End If

        If pos1 <> 0 And pos2 <> 0 Then Exit For
    Next i

    If pos1 <> 0 And pos2 <> 0 Then
        getTextBtwnNumbers = Trim(Mid(s, pos1, pos2 - pos1))
    Else
        getTextBtwnNumbers = "Invalid Text Format"
    End If
End Function
```

And then you can use it like this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim flName As String

    flName = "20170614Agreement01_MSD.xls"

    If getTextBtwnNumbers(flName) = "Agreement" Then
        MsgBox "Match Found"
    End If
End Sub
```

**Note:**

I am assuming that the text will be between 2 numbers in the format `NumberTEXTNumber`.

If you have a format which is `NumberTEXTONENumberTEXTTWONumber` then the function will only extract `TEXTONE`

**EDIT**

I realised that there is a better way using `LIKE`. This way you will not need the above function.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim flName As String, Searchtext As String

    flName = "20170614Agreement01_MSD.xls"

    Searchtext = "Agreement"

    If flName Like "*#" & Searchtext & "#*.xls" Then MsgBox "Match Found"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Siddhart. Thank you for taking the time to respond it is greatly appreciated. I like your code example as a solution but unfortunately the numbers at the front and back do not remain the same everytime. 20170614 is a date and this will change. But maybe we can work this another way, what if I had code that deleted characters in the file name.  I could then just tell the looping code hey look for "Agreement". Would this approach work???

Comment: It doesn't matter what the number is :) There has to be a number.. whatever that may be. It can be `111AAA222` or `20170614Agreement01_MSD` or `123345678SID43211456` or anything. The format has to be `NTN` (NumberTextNumber)

Comment: ah ok: I i will give that a try. I added some code there to begin on the other solution in your answer. Please ignore until I try your original approach :-) Oh and thank you for the support :-) much appreciated :-)

Comment: I already rejected your edit :) Please do not edit my answer to post clarification. Feel free to edit your question.

Comment: Sorry about that. I was unaware of that editing rule. I apologies for that. I have tried the approach you have kindly offered and the code now just loops through adding the Agreement headings to all files. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: `If getTextBtwnNumbers(flName) = "Agreement" Then` You need to change the word "Agreement" in that code with the relevant text which you want to check :)

Comment: I think you need to use it like this `If getTextBtwnNumbers(myFile) = "Agreement" Then`

Comment: Hi. Yes I made those changes but the code keeps going to the other files and adding the Agreement Text. It does what it is supposed to do with the Agreement file and then It keeps going

Comment: Can you update your question with the code that you are using?

Comment: Hi I just added the code that I am using now. It is a stripped down version but this is putting all the Text values into all the files present in the folder. Thank you again for the help. CODE piece is STRIP DOWN CODE FOR TEST

Comment: `myFile = "20170614Agreement01_MSD.xls"` You have hardcoded the file name and hence `If getTextBtwnNumbers(myFile) = "Agreement" Then` will always be true :) Remove that line. The `myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)` is already taking care of the filename.

Comment: BOO YAAAHH! Victory!! VICTORY lap STACK OVERFLOW VICTORY LAP :-) :-) thank you so much for all you help Siddharth. MUCH respect from Dublin that has worked like a Charm :-) THANK YOU

Comment: I realised that there is a much better way. I have updated the above post :

Comment: There is only one word for that, and that is 'SLICK' :-) That is some SLICK VBA right there :-) Thank you Siddharth much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use "And" in your "If" statements to do a more complex check of your file name.

By the way, if you want your "InStr" function to just check if a small string is *present* in a bigger string all you need to do is something like this:

```
If InStr(myFile, "Professional") Then
```

rather then this:

```
If InStr(myFile, "Professional") > 0 Then
```

This is kind of like returning "True" or "False" to your If...Then statement.

Here is my solution to your problem:

```
Public Sub testStr()
Dim strVar As String
Dim myFile As String

myFile = "ProfessionalStateLicense"

If InStr(myFile, "Professional") And InStr(myFile, "StateLicense") Then
  MsgBox myFile
  ' do specific case
End If

End Sub
```

Just replace "StateLicense" with the other examples of filenames' subtext that you have in your folder. For example, replace "StateLicense" with "Address".

There may be a way to use the "Select Case" method as well, but I believe it would take more work than my solution.